# iPhone Calculator App Unwanted Decimal Places

Tags: ios, calculator

I recently made watched a tutorial for an calculator iPhone app. It works however I am having an issue with unwanted decimal places, Meaning my app will put a dot after my number and have like 6 0s after it. I looked up how to fix this and tried what I saw, however it only works when I type in the first number in. When I click the Multiplication, Division, Subtraction, or Addition button they reappear and when it shows the answer it includes the unwanted decimals too. My code is below, Please Help me Thanks!

ViewController.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Simple Calculator
//
//  Created by Michael on 2013-08-08.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 com.company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    float result;
    IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorScreen;
    int currentOperation;
    float currentNumber;
    BOOL userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal;


}
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancelInput;
-(IBAction)cancelOperation;



@end
```

ViewController.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Simple Calculator
//
//  Created by Michael on 2013-08-08.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 com.company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {
    if (!userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal)
    {
    currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float ) [sender tag];
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d",(int)currentNumber];
    }
    else{
        calculatorScreen.text= [calculatorScreen.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]]];
        currentNumber = [calculatorScreen.text floatValue];
    }
}

-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {
    if (currentOperation == 0) result = currentNumber;
    else {
        switch (currentOperation) {
            case 1:
                result = result + currentNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                result = result - currentNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                result = result * currentNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                result = result / currentNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                currentOperation = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    currentNumber = 0;
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",result];
    if ([sender tag] == 0) result=0;
    currentOperation = [sender tag];
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = NO;    
}

-(IBAction)cancelInput {
    currentNumber = (int)(currentNumber/10);
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",currentNumber];;
}

-(IBAction) cancelOperation {
    currentNumber = 0;
    calculatorScreen.text = @"0";
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = NO;
}

- (IBAction)dotPressed{
    if(!userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal){
        userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = YES;
        calculatorScreen.text= [calculatorScreen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Thanks :)

Comment: P.S I'm very new to this so try to make your answer easy for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your **buttonOperationPressed:sender** method you're missing a period in your format string:

```
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",result];
```

should be
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",result];

i.e. %.2f instead of %2f.

If you want the padding as well then you can use %2.2f instead.

Here's a tutorial on [format specifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).